# Is there any way to make this flat array more compact?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there is some way to make it shorter:

```
someObj.array1
  .map((item) => item.array2)
  .flat()
  .map((item) => item.array3)
  .flat()
  .map((item) => item.array4)
  .flat();
```

Comment: Use `.flatMap`?

Comment: Can you share what `someObj.array1` looks like?

Comment: please add `array1`.

Comment: use `array1.flat(Infinity)`

Comment: @matrixersp the object to flatten clearly contains elements that are objects with one property being an array, so using `Array.prototype.flat(Infinity)` would not work

Comment: @georg array1: [{array2: [{array3: [{array4: [1, 2, 3, 4]}]}]}, {}]
every object has some other properties than array2, array3 etc.

Comment: es6, [].concat(...array1)

Comment: @Laudinio: please edit your post so that everyone sees that. Also, add the expected result.

Comment: @VLAZ correct. it works: someObj.array1
  .flatMap((item) => item.array2)
  .flatMap((item) => item.array3)
  .flatMap((item) => item.array4);

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach by handing over the initial array and the wanted keys.

```
function flat(array, [key, ...rest]) {
    return key
        ? flat(array.map(item => item[key]).flat(), rest)
        : array;
}

console.log(flat(someObj.array1, ['array2', 'array3', 'array4']));
```